# update multiple documents in mongodb from spring mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

In my use case I want to update multiple documents at once, documents that match a query, using spring-data-mongo.

Here is what I have been trying,

```
Criteria filterCriteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("bac").is("def"));
        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("status", status);
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(filterCriteria);
        mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, MyClass.class);
```

But this is not updating any document.

Plus I have looked up in the mongo documentation but have not anything useful
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method

Here is the version that I am using

1. Mongodb - 3.6
2. spring-data-mongodb - 1.5.5.RELEASE

Comment: any particular reason for using add in query when you have just on clause in query ? Did you try query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("bac").is("def"));
Also can you try enabling debug logs for mongodb so that we can see native query getting executed. This can be done by adding a property logger.level. org.springframework.data.mongodb.core=debug in application.properties if it is spring boot project

Comment: also the documentation link you shared. It says - findAndModify, updates only one document so instead we need to consider update function which when passed multi will update more than one document in store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAndModify(...)` method can update a document and return either the old or newly updated document in a single operation.

To update all document that matches the given query use `updateMulti(...)`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#updateMulti-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.UpdateDefinition-java.lang.Class-

visit the link and there you will find it.

[image]

Comment: There is no such class as UpdateMulti

Comment: this documentataion is for spring-data-mongodb...I hope it will help you..

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowire
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

Query query = new Query();
Criteria filterCriteria = Criteria.where("bac").is("def");
query.addCriteria(filterCriteria);
Update update = new Update();
update.set("status", status);
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, MyClass.class);
```